# Null Reference getting REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an ASMX web service running under IIS7 in classic mode. This service has the following code:

```
   try
   {
       env.ExternalIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

       LogWriter.WriteError(ex);
       env.ExternalIP="000.000.000.000";
   }
```

This results in the following stack trace. I only modified the names of usercode call stack here to protect the innocent:

```
Message: An Exception of type: NullReferenceException occured in method:  GetAdditionalServerVar
ExceptionMsg: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
===Stack Trace===
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetAdditionalServerVar(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetServerVariable(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.AddServerVariableToCollection(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInServerVariablesCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Populate()
   at System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Get(String name)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at MyService.MyMethod()
```

I'm at a loss here as this is very basic plain vanilla code.

**EDIT**

This gets even stranger. I have added some basic code just wondering what server variables I can get at this point. This fails with the same exception when I try and get all the keys:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetAdditionalServerVar(Int32
>   index)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetServerVariable(String
>   name)    at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.AddServerVariableToCollection(String
>   name)    at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInServerVariablesCollection()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Populate()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.get_AllKeys()
>   at MyService.MyHelper()

When I was looking at the framework code looks like this could happen when the array which caches the server variables isn't populated and it looks like this occurs when there a null pointer to some Context...which seems like a fairly core piece of the framework code.

I suppose it's time to burn up one of our support tickets with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through my old questions. I believe this was caused by a bug in either .net or IIS. Essentially, the web service was marked as Oneway. By doing so the user was disconnected before the handler was executed so unless you managed to access the Request variables prior to the handler executing you would encounter a null reference exception.

The workaround was to add an HTTP module which accessed the property earlier in the pipeline before the client was sent the response and the handler was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the ip directly from [`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not always populated depending on the proxies... http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx

Comment: Yes but it shouldn't cause a null reference exception. It would just return the proxies IP address which is fine...I want something not an exception